# How to solve Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a formula like this. But the formula has an error. Please help me.

```
select 
    [DAY] as [DAY],
    [Name] as [Name],
    ((cast([columnA] + [columnB] + [columnC] as bigint) * 1000) / NULLIF(8 * 1024 * 1048576, 0)) as [TotalColumn]
from 
    [TableA]
```

Error message:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: What datatypes are columnA, columnB, columnC?
Could you give us some example values (ideally that cause the error)?

Comment: This is your issue: `NULLIF(8*1024*1048576,0)`

Comment: The error is perfectly correct. `8*1024*1048576` is not going to fit into a `int` on (m)any current systems.

Comment: What is the content of columnA, columnB and columnC? What do you think `NULLIF` is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying at your end, but you can use **NUMERIC** datatype as the results can contain decimal places.

```
select 
'Monday' as [DAY],
'Septiana Fajrin' as [Name],
((cast('5' + '5' + '5' as Numeric) * 1000) / (convert(Numeric, 8) * 1024 * 1048576))as [TotalColumn]
```

### Result

```
DAY Name    TotalColumn
Monday  Septiana Fajrin 0.000064610503613
```

Answer (score 4):

Since your dividend is a bigint I suspect you will need the divisor to also be a bigint. Since you have some integer literals the math will attempt to put that in an int and it is too large. You can however force the divisor to be a bigint.

```
convert(bigint, 8) * 1024 * 1048576
```

Comment: It is your formula. What do you mean it is too large? That makes no sense. If those numbers are not what you want then you need to change your formula to whatever it should be. I provided you an answer as to why you were getting the error message.