# How to solve Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 25 Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql-server

Following the question that was raised [How to solve Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852093/how-to-solve-msg-8115-level-16-state-2-line-2-arithmetic-overflow-error-conve)

I am wondering what does the LEVEL, STAGE and LINE stand for? Could it help to spot which column/ line is causing the error?
Thank you!

Comment: [Understanding SQL Server errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/understanding-database-engine-errors?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Level - 11-16:Indicate errors that can be corrected by the user. You may want to read more about it in MSDN.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-2017

For error state , in this case it might not be useful but in most of the cases, you can customized your code and be able to change your application or stored proc execution based on state of the error.

Line number is of course the line number of code.

Hope that helps.